# Split worksheets into workbooks in a single folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create multiple Excel workbooks by separating out each worksheet in a single workbook with:

```
 Sub Splitbook()
 MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
 For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
 sht.Copy
 '(I got an error here-copy method of worksheet class failed)
 ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
 ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
 ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
 Filename:=MyPath & "\" & sht.Name & ".xls"
 ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
 Next sht
 End Sub
```

I have used the same code for a different workbook and it worked but am now seeing the copy method of worksheet class failed error.

Can anyone explain why and how to fix this please?

Comment: I have used the same code for different workbook and it worked but for this it isnt working.

Comment: Please go through this http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

There are several complications with your code in order to perform the described task. I have modified your code in order to make it create individual workbooks out of all the worksheets in your active workbook.

```
Sub Splitbook()
    Dim CurWb As Workbook, NewWb As Workbook
    Dim MyPath As String
    MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Set CurWb = ActiveWorkbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Loops through all sheets in active workbook
    For Each CurWs In CurWb.Worksheets
        'Copy sheet to new workbook
        CurWb.Sheets(CurWs.Name).Copy After:=Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1)
        Set NewWb = ActiveWorkbook

        'Removes empty sheets, saves workbook and closes workbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For Each NewWs In NewWb.Worksheets
            If NewWs.Name <> CurWs.Name Then NewWs.Delete
        Next NewWs
        NewWb.SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & "\" & CurWs.Name & ".xls", FileFormat:=56
        NewWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next CurWs

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to check the sheet which is copied is visible. Please give this a try and let me know the results.

```
Sub Splitbook()
    MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

        If sht.Visible = True Then
            sht.Copy
            '(I got an error here-copy method of worksheet class failed)
            ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
            ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
                    Filename:=MyPath & "\" & sht.Name & ".xls"
            ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        End If
    Next sht
End Sub
```

Comment: @Soren Holten Hansen and Santosh.Thanks for the guidance.